# Powershell read file for filename and path

Tags: file, powershell, extract

I have the following script which runs on .zip files in a directory which have a whole directory structure with many files. These files then have 7zip run on them to extract them and then .eml is added to the extracted file.

```
& "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x c:\TestZip -r -oC:\TestRestore 2> c:\TestLog\ziplog.txt
& "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x c:\TestRestore -r -aos -oc:\TestExtract 2> c:\TestLog\sevenzip.txt
gci -path "c:\TestExtract" -file | rename-item -newname {$PSItem.name + ".eml"}
```

My problem is that out of these files sometimes the final extraction cannot be done by 7zip as it does not see it as an archive. I have found that these particular files if I just put .eml on them they are accessible as emails. So when the archive fails to extract I write the output to the sevenzip.txt file.
What I need help with is how do I read this file to get the filenames and place them in a directory so I can add the .eml extension.
An example of the output in the sevenzip.txt file is as follows

```
ERROR: c:\TestRestore\0\0\54\3925ccb78f80d28b7569b6759554d.0_4011
Can not open the file as archive


ERROR: c:\TestRestore\0\0\5b\6fa7acb219dec5d9e55d4eadd6eb1.0_3958
Can not open the file as archive
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to do this.

Sorry for all the comments but I am working on this

```
$SourceFile = 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt'
$DestinationFile = 'c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt'
$Pattern = 'c:\\TestRestore\\' (Get-Content $SourceFile) | 
    % {if ($_ -match $Pattern){$_}} | 
    Set-Content $DestinationFile (Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('ERROR: ', '') | 
    Set-Content $DestinationFile (Get-Content$DestinationFile).replace('7z.exe : ', '') | 
    Set-Content $DestinationFile
```

Comment: I am thinking I should be able to use something like get-content but I am not very good at programming so I am open to any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but I am working on this                                                                                                         $SourceFile = 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt'
$DestinationFile = 'c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt'
$Pattern = 'c:\\TestRestore\\'

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -match $Pattern){$_}} | Set-Content $DestinationFile
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('ERROR: ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('7z.exe : ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no other errors, then you can pick those filenames out of the file with a regex pattern match:

```
$filesToFix = Select-String -Pattern "ERROR: (.*)" -LiteralPath 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt' | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

And probably rename them with

```
$filesToFix | ForEach-Object {

    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_ -NewName {"$_.eml"}
}
```

If there might be other errors and you only want these, you'll need more work on the matching:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content -LiteralPath 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt' -Raw

$filesToFix = [regex]::Matches($fileContent, 
                 "ERROR: (.*)\nCan not open the file as archive",
                 'Multiline') | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I used `code` # This section creates a list of all the files that failed to extract with their directory location. For use in next section. 

$SourceFile = 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt'
$DestinationFile = 'c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt'
$Pattern = 'c:\\TestRestore\\'

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -match $Pattern){$_}} | Set-Content $DestinationFile
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('ERROR: ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('7z.exe : ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile `code`

Comment: Sorry don't know how to format my text correctly or place a carriage return in a comment `code` Get-Content C:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt | Measure-Object –Line > c:\testlog\numberoffilesthatfailed.txt

#This copies all files listed in the txt file to another directory

type c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt | copy-item -destination "c:\TestCopy"

#This renames the current extensions to .eml

gci -path "C:\TestCopy" -file | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::changeextension($_.name, "eml")} `code`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended going with it is in the comments because I didn't know how to format but have worked it out now so hopefully this makes it easier to understand in case it is useful.

This section creates a list of all the files that failed to extract with their directory location. For use in next section.

`$SourceFile = 'c:\testlog\sevenzip.txt' $DestinationFile = c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt'
$Pattern = 'c:\\TestRestore\\' 
(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -match $Pattern){$_}} | Set-Content $DestinationFile 
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('ERROR: ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile 
(Get-Content $DestinationFile).replace('7z.exe : ', '') | Set-Content $DestinationFile`

This is just some result checking

`Get-Content C:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt | Measure-Object –Line > c:\testlog\numberoffilesthatfailed.txt`

This copies all files listed in the txt file to another directory

`c:\testlog\testlogextractnew.txt | copy-item -destination "c:\TestCopy"`

This renames the current extensions to .eml

`gci -path "C:\TestCopy" -file | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::changeextension($_.name, "eml")}`